# I want to delete a row from InDatagridview that contains textbox.tex and transfer it to OutDatagridview

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete a row from InDatagridview that contains textbox.tex and transfer it to OutDatagridview

if i change the value of textbox it will search to InDatagridview and delete a row from InDatagridview that contains textbox.tex and transfer it to OutDatagridview.

If i change again the textbox value it will search to OutDatagridview and delete a row from OutDatagridview that contains textbox.text
and transfer it to InDatagridview.

Thanks!!!! a lot

Comment: Congratulations.  Get to it and, if you encounter an issue along the way that we can help with, let us know.  In the mean time, you might read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to "transfer" DGV rows from one to another control.  A DataView makes it easy to show data in different contexts with almost no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim found, x, z As Boolean
            Dim lookfor As String = Student_numberTextBox.Text
            For dgv As Integer = In_TableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If In_TableDataGridView.RowCount > 0 Then
                    If lookfor = In_TableDataGridView.Rows(dgv).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
                        found = True

                    End If
                Else
                    found = False
                End If
            Next





            If found = False Then

                'In_TableBindingSource.AddNew()


                If Out_tableDataGridView.RowCount > 0 Then
                    x = True
                Else
                    x = False
                End If

                If x = True Then


                    Dim textout As String = Student_numberTextBox.Text
                    For inrow As Integer = Out_tableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

                        If textout = Out_tableDataGridView.Rows(inrow).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then

                            Dim row2 As DataGridViewRow
                            row2 = Out_tableDataGridView.Rows(inrow)
                            Out_tableDataGridView.Rows.Remove(row2)


                        Else

                            'Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                End If

            End If


            If found = True Then
                'Out_tableBindingSource.AddNew()



                If In_TableDataGridView.RowCount > 0 Then
                    z = True
                Else
                    z = False
                End If


                If z = True Then

                    Dim textin As String = Student_numberTextBox.Text
                    For outrow As Integer = In_TableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1


                        If textin = In_TableDataGridView.Rows(outrow).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then

                            Dim row1 As DataGridViewRow
                            row1 = In_TableDataGridView.Rows(outrow)
                            In_TableDataGridView.Rows.Remove(row1)

                        Else

                            'Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                End If`enter code here`


            End If

        End If
```